# How to forward logs to new relic from nestjs?

Tags: nestjs, newrelic

I have configured new relic to monitor my nest app. Everything works fine. But, the only issue I am facing is with logging. I have enabled the application_logging but I am not seeing any logs in new relic dashboard. I don't understand the issue.

newrelic.js file code:

```
exports.config = {
    app_name: ['appName'],
    license_key: 'KEY',
    logging: {
        level: 'info',
        filepath: 'stdout',
    },
    allow_all_headers: true,
    attributes: {
        custom_key: 'custom_value',
    },
    error_collector: {
        enabled: true,
    },
    transaction_tracer: {
        enabled: true,
    },
    application_logging: {
        forwarding: {
            enabled: true,
        },
    },
    browser_monitoring: {
        enable: true,
    },
};
```

I am using winston for logging. winston configuration:

```
import * as winston from 'winston';
const newrelicFormatter = require('@newrelic/winston-enricher');

const newrelicWinstonFormatter = newrelicFormatter(winston);

const logger = winston.createLogger({
    format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.colorize({ all: true }),
        winston.format.timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' }),
        newrelicWinstonFormatter(),
        winston.format.printf(({ level, timestamp, message }) => {
            return `${timestamp} [${level}] - ${message}`;
        })
    ),
    transports: [new winston.transports.Console()],
});
```